# How to work with GMSMapViewDelegate in view

Tags: google-maps, swiftui

GMSMapViewDelegate how to work in view where I can access infwindow maker function Swiftui

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get the question, but I think you need to access the `UIWindow` instance.

I made a simple `ViewModifier` that allows you to access the window your view is being displayed in.

Usage:

```swift
Text("Hello World")
  .onWindow { window in 
    // ...
  }
```

Implementation

```swift
extension View {
    public func onWindow(_ foo: @escaping (UIWindow) -> Void) -> some View {
        self.background(WindowGrabber(onWindow: foo))
    }
}

private struct WindowGrabber: UIViewRepresentable {
    let onWindow: (UIWindow) -> Void
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let window = view.window {
                self.onWindow(window)
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewRepresentable { I have markers at map now I want to show custom info window according to mine requirements I am very confused how I will use GMSMapViewDelegate here in this structure to use this function mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView { } I need help how to access GMSMapViewDelegate to use

}